# Conflict on numbering equation and thm?

Tags: thmtools

I'm trying to number equations following theorem-like environments. So I write

```
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,sibling=equation]{thm}
```

But then there are errors:

> Command \@thm already defined.
>
> No counter 'thm' defined.
>
> \thm undefined.

However, even if I change my code to

```
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,sibling=equation]{theorem}
```

or something other than "thm", the problem disappears.

**I wonder why this happens?**

Here is my sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,sibling=equation]{thm}

\begin{document}
\section{MWS}
\begin{thm}
content
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Congratulations! You found a bug in `thmtools`. I sent mail to the package author.

Comment: presumably you're using `thmtools` for a particular reason, so this may be irrelevant, but it's an alternate methos.  using `amsthm` just specify your theorem objects this way: `\newtheorem{thm}[equation]{Theorem}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exposes a nasty bug of `thmtools`. At line 59 of the auxiliary package `aliasctr.sty` we find

```
\@ifdefinable{c@#1}{%
```

as part of the definition of `\@counteralias`. It is a bad error, because `\@ifdefinable` expects a single token as its argument and havoc ensues if this part of the code is executed.

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% fix the bug in aliasctr.sty
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@counteralias}
 {\@ifdefinable{c@#1}}
 {\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname c@#1\endcsname}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Theorem,
  sibling=equation,
]{thm}


\begin{document}
\section{MWS}
\begin{thm}
content
\end{thm}
\begin{equation}
1=1
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]